# Styling a data-tooltip with CSS

Tags: css, tooltip, styling

I'm trying to add styling to a CSS "data-tooltip" (more specifically trying to make the tooltip background black). But I'm not succeeding. Please check out the the screen-shot below:

[image]

As you can see, the `span[data-tooltip]:hover` styling is not getting activated even when I hover over the element. Instead of showing a black background, it is showing a white background.

What am I doing wrong? Wasted a couple of hours searching for a solution! Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to style the SVG instead.

Comment: Have a look in the 'computed' tab and see if it's inheriting the white background from a parent element. It's very hard to know without being able to look at your code in a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Toxnyc I tried styling the SVG too. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @cfranklin The 'computed' tab shows it's getting the background-color attribute from the span[data-tooltip] element and not from a parent element. What I don't understand is: how is the span[data:tooltip] element is active when I hover over the element, but not the span[data:tooltip]:hover? About the JSFiddle, I'm afraid I'm editing the theme for Discourse forum software; there are simply too many CSS files to post a JSFiddle.